# Regex - How to replace period in file name with an underscore

Tags: regex

I'm looking to build a regular expression that will allow me to replace the periods (.) in a filename with an underscore (_).

**Example:** replace filename.doc with filename_doc

I've had a play around in Expresso, and have worked out that it will be something like .\w{3,4) - to pick up 3 or 4 character extentions eg doc, docx, xls, xlsx etc.

But I cannot figure out how to replace only the period and retain the extention.

Comment: why do you want to use regex for this? virtually every language supports simple char/string replace - something like myString.replace( '.', '_' );

Comment: Do you want to replace only the last dot or all of them?

Comment: I normally would just do what you have described, but due to some very strange restrictions of another system I am passing the string to, I only want to replace the periods that are contained within filenames.

Comment: you mean you have plain text that may contain some filenames? oh boy, how about stuff like `jquery.js`? you can't really assume it is a filename just because / only when there's a dot followed by 3-4 characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape `.` sign. Try with following regex:

```
\.(\w{3,4})$
```

And replace it with:

```
_$1
```

`$1` contains matched string in `()`

Comment: I did have the period escaped, but It seems to have been stripped from my post? But thanks for the answer, it was the $1 that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

To replace only the last dot:

```
perl:  $str =~ s/\.([^.]+)$/_$1/

php: $str = preg_replace('/\.([^.]+)$/', "_$1", $str);
```

Replace all the dots:

```
perl: $str =~ s/\./_/g;

php: $str = preg_replace('/\./', '_', $str);
```